# Why is android code coverage file coverage.ec use device name as prefix?

Tags: android, jacoco

I was able to generate jacoco test report before untill recently I found out that the normal `coverage.ec` file got renamed to `Nexus_5X_API_26(AVD) - 8.0.0-coverage.ec`(**looks like device name + coverage.ec**), thus my gradle script wasn't able to locate it unless I manually update to use the new file name.

Is there a way to get the device name from gradle script so when I run the task to combine coverage report it will be able to find the coverage file.

Comment: did you got any answer?